# how to fix java.io.FileNotFoundExpection and install ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA certificate in jmeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

#jmeter #performance_testing

[jmeter recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xGur.jpg)
whenever i try to create a ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA certificate .it will not create and shown the mentioned notification. plese help me to resolve this.

i am try to run the http scribt recorder in jmeter but i is not working.

help me to run the http recording test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter tries to create the `proxyserver.jks` file under it's "bin" folder and it doesn't look like the user you're launching JMeter from has write permissions to that folder.

You either need to:

- Use [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) or [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) command to grant your current user the write permissions to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
- Or amend `proxy.cert.file` [JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert) to point to the location where you have write access to (normally it should be inside your user [home folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory))

In any case the JMeter version you're using is kind of too old, as per [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version):

> The performance of JMeter is being constantly improved, so users are highly encouraged to use the most up to date version.
> Ensure you always read changes list to be aware of new improvements and components. You should absolutely avoid using versions that are older than 3 versions before the last one.

So it worth [installing the latest stable version of JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) ([JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) as of now)